# Rounded UIImageView with border - raw edges

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-graphics

I'm trying to get smooth corners, but without success.
This is how it looks:

[image]

I have Subclass of UIImageView where in layoutSubviews I have the logic for putting the rounded corner for uiimageview, and it's clipped to bounds.

But I'm not getting why some images are drawn with these raw edges, and they are OUT of the border layer...

Because it's clipped, I can't make a custom layer with different frame for border, because whole superlayer is clipped.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
    {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.layer setCornerRadius:self.frame.size.width/2];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:BORDERSIZE];
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[BORDERCOLOR CGColor]];
        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To make the circular imageview use this following code in viewDidLoad. For clipped to bounds set it to yes.

```
self.MyImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.MyImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
self.MyImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

To apply the border use this code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.MyImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
self.MyImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

This will definitely works out.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: That means you are not using square image view which might have trouble you in shape. Other wise it will definitely works. Try using square imageview  & use my code once you will find solution.